# Sspring-boot app in docker container consumes high CPU without being used

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, garbage-collection

I have a very strange issue. I have a java web app (spring boot 1.5) which runs inside a docker container.

At some point the app starts consuming the CPU quire hard. 
So i was thinking that the app itself has a bug of some sort.

BUT

If i remove the app from the load balancer, so it will no accept any connections, the app continues to consume a lot of CPU, even it is not accessed at all.

I continue to see a lot of GC log entries from the app in the log file.
It seems that the JVM continues to run GC on Young gen every 300ms, even when the app should be completely idle (and it is idle as there is nothing in the logfile)!

The app itself is just a website using spring boot. Nothing really special there (no scheduled task or what so ever).

Any idea what might going on here ? Can it be docker related ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set min and max java memory flag for your application? If other applications are working, your application may have insufficient memory -> GG is cleaning more than it should.

Comment: Yes I did. I tried different configurations between 2 and 4gb. Behaves the same. I set only xmx thought. The app doesn't even use it all

Comment: Could you please paste the docker-compose file or docker run command?

Comment: Something like this
docker run -it -p 11099:1099 -v /tmp:/logs -v /tmp:/tmp registry:5000/java-jre:8 java -Dserver.port=9999 -Xmx2g \
 -jar /tmp/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,classpath:/application-prod.properties

Answer (score 0):

OK,
it turns out this had nothing to do with docker. Was a bug in the app, creating many(unnecessary) short lived objects which needed GC.